# How do I mock guzzle request

Tags: laravel, testing, mocking, phpunit, guzzle

How do I make a mock of third party api call . That is happening from controller . I have this line of code in controller .

```
public function store(){
  $response =    $request->post('http://thirdpaty.app/rmis/api/ebp/requests', [
                  "headers" => [
                      'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                   ],
                "json" => [
                  "data"=>1
                   ]
            ]);
                $data = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());
                $token = $data->token;

         // Saving that token to database

}
```

And from the test I am doing

```
$response = $this->post('/to-store-method');
```

How do I mock the api request . So that in testing I don't have to call the third api request .

Right now I am doing

```
if(app()->get('env') == 'testing'){
     $token = 123;
}else{
     //Api call here
  }
```

Is there any better alternative of doing this test

Answer (score 1):

You'll need some way of injecting a mock handler into the Guzzle Client your controller is using. Traditionally, you'd either leverage dependency injection by passing the Guzzle Client via the constructor or through some referenced service in that code that you can mock (using Mockery) behind the scenes.

After that, check out the Guzzle documentation for a peak on how to mock requests in the HTTP Client:

http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/testing.html

You'd use a MockHandler to do something resembling the following code by building a stack of fake requests and responses.

```
// Create a mock and queue two responses.
$mock = new MockHandler([
    new Response(200, ['X-Foo' => 'Bar'], 'Hello, World'),
    new Response(202, ['Content-Length' => 0]),
    new RequestException('Error Communicating with Server', new Request('GET', 'test'))
]);

$handlerStack = HandlerStack::create($mock);
$client = new Client(['handler' => $handlerStack]);

// The first request is intercepted with the first response.
$response = $client->request('GET', '/');
```

Comment: Do you know a way on how to inject it?